# Sharing My Location using maps in my iOS App?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm developing a demo family app. I want to add a location map feature in one of the tabs. Where users can see the location I pinned.

Let us say, there is a family event going on, and I want to share the location with the users who has the app. So, they simply, check the tab and see the location on google map inside my app.

Can you give me any tips from where to start or if there is a read library to work on?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you're going to want to use [Location Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH1-SW1).

Once you've determined that Location services are available, you set them up and provide a delegate implementing CLLocationManagerDelegate.  Among other things, there is a callback that is fired when the user's location changes. You'll want to handle the location change here and store the user's location for use in your application.

```
   // Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.    
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager    
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation    
    fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation    
{    
    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power    
    NSDate* eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;    
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0)
    {
        NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
                newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    }

    // else skip the event and process the next one.
}
```